# Flexbox link button response issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

the issue I am having is that before I add links to my icons it is laid out visually how I want it. Then when I attach links to them to make them clickable their positions change. I cannot pinpoint exactly what is causing this issue so if anyone knows or can see it that would really help. Thanks! The first snippet is the design and layout I want and the second snippet is the issue with the links.

```css
.container {
     display: flex;
    background-color: #1DA0A3;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width:1700px;            
    margin: 0 auto;      
}
  
  .box{
    flex: 1 0 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    margin:1em;
  
   transition: all 0.3 ease-in-out;
 
  }

.box::after{
 z-index:-1;
 opacity:0;
 box-shadow:0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover{
 transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px black;
}

.box:hover:after{
 opacity:1;
}
  
  .box img{
    align-self: center;
    width: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
   padding-top:10px;
  }
  
  .box .buy{
    align-self: center;
    margin-top: auto;
  }


.flexwords{
 align-self: center;
 margin-top: auto;
}

#contacticon{
  width:100px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="colorbk">

   <div class="container">
    
   <div class="box">
      <img src="computericon.svg" alt="" id="lapicon" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">My Work</h2>
      
    </div>
    
   <div class="box">
      <img src="haticon.svg" alt=""  id="haticon" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">My Education</h2>
    </div>
        
    
    <div class="box">
      <img src="tieicon.svg" id="contacticon" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">Contact Me</h2>
      
    </div>
      
       
<br>

<hr class="hr1">


<div class="wrap">
<main>
<aside>
 <h1>Do You Want to...</h1>
    <ul>
  <li>Rebrand yourself online</li>
  <li>Take your current website and make it modern</li>
  <li>Find a way to make information more accessible for customers</li>
  <li> Improve customer service</li>
  <li> Reach a wider range of people</li>
</ul>
</aside>
<article>
<h1>Do You Want to...</h1>

<ul>
  <li>Create forms and documents that customers can fill out online</li>
  <li>Start an email list for recurring customers</li>
  <li>Show relatability with your audience</li>
  <li> Have 24/7 online exposure</li>
  <li>Create a map or a way for customers to find your location</li>
</ul>
</article>

</main>
</div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

```css
.container {
     display: flex;
    background-color: #1DA0A3;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width:1700px;            
    margin: 0 auto;      
}
  
  .box{
    flex: 1 0 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    margin:1em;
  
   transition: all 0.3 ease-in-out;
 
  }

.box::after{
 z-index:-1;
 opacity:0;
 box-shadow:0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover{
 transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px black;
}

.box:hover:after{
 opacity:1;
}
  
  .box img{
    align-self: center;
    width: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
   padding-top:10px;
  }
  
  .box .buy{
    align-self: center;
    margin-top: auto;
  }


.flexwords{
 align-self: center;
 margin-top: auto;
}

#contacticon{
  width:100px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="colorbk">

   <div class="container">
    
   <a href="skills.html"><div class="box">
      <img src="computericon.svg" alt="" id="lapicon" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">My Work</h2>
      
    </div></a>
    
    <a href="about.html"><div class="box">
      <img src="haticon.svg" alt=""  id="haticon" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">My Education</h2>
    </div></a>
        
    
     <a href="contact.html"><div class="box">
      <img src="tieicon.svg" id="contacticon" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">Contact Me</h2>
      
    </div></a>
      
       
<br>

<hr class="hr1">


<div class="wrap">
<main>
<aside>
 <h1>Do You Want to...</h1>
    <ul>
  <li>Rebrand yourself online</li>
  <li>Take your current website and make it modern</li>
  <li>Find a way to make information more accessible for customers</li>
  <li> Improve customer service</li>
  <li> Reach a wider range of people</li>
</ul>
</aside>
<article>
<h1>Do You Want to...</h1>

<ul>
  <li>Create forms and documents that customers can fill out online</li>
  <li>Start an email list for recurring customers</li>
  <li>Show relatability with your audience</li>
  <li> Have 24/7 online exposure</li>
  <li>Create a map or a way for customers to find your location</li>
</ul>
</article>

</main>
</div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace the `div` with the anchor `a`, and set the `box` class to it

```css
body {
  background-image: url(footer_lodyas.png);
}
ml,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
/***************flexbox icons************/

.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #1DA0A3;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  margin: 1em;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.box img {
  align-self: center;
  width: 180px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.box .buy {
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: auto;
}
.flexwords {
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: auto;
}
#contacticon {
  width: 100px;
}
/****************horizontal line*************/

.hr1 {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #293839;
  margin-left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  color: #485A5F;
  height: 2px;
}
/***************Do you want to section*************/

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
aside,
article {
  padding: 2em;
}
aside {
  flex: 0 auto;
}
article {
  flex: 0 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <a class="box" href="skills.html">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/iMac-icon.png" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">My Work</h2>
    </a>

    <a class="box" href="about.html">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/iMac-icon.png" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">My Education</h2>
    </a>

    <a class="box" href="contact.html">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/iMac-icon.png" id="contacticon" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">Contact Me</h2>
    </a>

    <br>

    <hr class="hr1">


    <div class="wrap">
      <main>
        <aside>
          <h1>Do You Want to...</h1>
          <ul>
            <li>Rebrand myself online</li>
            <li>Take my current website and make it modern</li>
            <li>Find a way to make information more accessible for customers</li>
            <li>Improve customer service</li>
            <li>Reach a wider range of people</li>
          </ul>
        </aside>
        <article>
          <h1>Do You Want to...</h1>

          <ul>
            <li>Create forms and documents that customers can fill out online</li>
            <li>Start an email list for recurring customers</li>
            <li>Show relatability with my audience</li>
            <li>Have 24/7 online exposure</li>
            <li>Create a map or a way for customers to find my location</li>
          </ul>
        </article>

      </main>
    </div>
```

Comment: This worked seamlessly! Thank you @LGSon I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `.box` to the `a` elements instead of the divs inside of them.

```
<div id="colorbk">

   <div class="container">

   <a href="skills.html" class="box"><div>
      <img src="computericon.svg" alt="" id="lapicon" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">My Work</h2>

    </div></a>

    <a href="about.html" class="box"><div>
      <img src="haticon.svg" alt=""  id="haticon" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">My Education</h2>
    </div></a>


     <a href="contact.html" class="box"><div >
      <img src="tieicon.svg" id="contacticon" alt="" />
      <h2 class="flexwords">Contact Me</h2>

    </div></a>


<br>

<hr class="hr1">


<div class="wrap">
<main>
<aside>
    <h1>Do You Want to...</h1>
    <ul>
  <li>Rebrand yourself online</li>
  <li>Take your current website and make it modern</li>
  <li>Find a way to make information more accessible for customers</li>
  <li> Improve customer service</li>
  <li> Reach a wider range of people</li>
</ul>
</aside>
<article>
<h1>Do You Want to...</h1>

<ul>
  <li>Create forms and documents that customers can fill out online</li>
  <li>Start an email list for recurring customers</li>
  <li>Show relatability with your audience</li>
  <li> Have 24/7 online exposure</li>
  <li>Create a map or a way for customers to find your location</li>
</ul>
</article>

</main>
</div>
 </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s70u1ddz/